# Extract/Subscribe to Mono value for return type on generated interface method

Tags: java, mono, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have an interface that I am implementing that is generated from a WSDL, so I can't change the signatures.  One of the methods returns a `List<Attributes>` with `Attributes` being another WSDL generated class.  The call flow has been updated to be reactive, and the Mono is bubbled all the way up the chain to this implementing class.

```
public List<Attributes> getUserProfile(final String filterValue);
```

The `return` statement calls a method that returns a `Mono<UserProfile>` which is then passed to another method that returns the `List`, but I cannot figure out how to subscribe to this to get the `List` so that my code compiles and works in a ***non-blocking*** way?

```
@Override
public List<Attributes> getUserProfile(final String filterValue) {

    return getUserProfile(serviceName, filterValue)
            .map(userProfile -> userProfileToAttributeList(userProfile));
//            .subscribe(userProfile -> userProfileToAttributeList(userProfile));
//            .map(listAttributes -> listAttributes);

//    Mono<UserProfile> userProfileMono = getUserProfile(serviceName, filterValue);
//    return userProfileMono.subscribe(userProfile -> userProfileToAttributeList(userProfile));
}

private Mono<UserProfile> getUserProfile(final String serviceName,final String filterValue) {
    return myService.getUserProfile(serviceName, filterValue);
}

private List<Attributes> userProfileToAttributeList(final UserProfile userProfile) {
    return userProfile.getAttributes().stream().map(MyServiceEndpoint::newAttribute).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Who calls `List<Attributes> getUserProfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't change the method signature to return `Mono` or `Flux` there is no other way around it, you need to block to get the "real" `List<Attributes>`.

Reactive only works if the complete operation is reactive on each step. Since this method "says" it will return `List<Attributes>` and not "promises" to return a `List<Attributes>` at some point in the future when needed and requested you have no option here.